# HVAC Fan Set to Continuous By Landlord- Please help me rewire

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

I live in an apartment in which the landlord has set the HVAC fan to be continuously blowing even with Auto Fan setting on.  Fan will also blow when Thermostat is turned off.   Please help me rewire this so that I can reduce my ever so large electricity bill!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post the manufacturer and model number of the thermostat

Comment: Braeburn 2020NC

Comment: It's possible that it was wired this way due to a malfunction of the circuit board in the furnace.  I had a furnace fan stop during the middle of winter and the tech bypassed the faulty switch on the board to cause the fan to be always on as a temporary fix until I decided if I wanted to replace the board (~$800) or just replace the entire 20yo furnace ($1800).  I let it run that way for about 6mo before finally replacing the furnace and it only increased my bill by about $15-20/mo.  Moral of the story is that really should contact your LL to find out why it is wired that way.

Answer (score 7):

***WARNING:*** Tampering with equipment that does not belong to you, could lead to eviction and/or legal action against you.

If you have the property owner remove the jumper that's between the `R` terminal and the `G` terminal in the furnace,  that should solve your problem.  However, if they do that, they'll want to connect the green `G` wire to the `G` terminal instead. Otherwise the fan will not function properly.

[image]

---

Since you are **NOT** the property owner, you should not make any modifications without permission from the owner.

Comment: *"WARNING: Tampering with equipment that does not belong to you, could lead to eviction and/or legal action against you."* ................ Which is why I'd never give advice in situations like this. His recourse is to contact the LL, or the housing department.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey you might be right.  I guess I figured I'd rather tell them how to do it, than have them damage the system trying to tamper with it.